# Short story from an anthology: school children use superior military strategy to defeat an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion, first-contact

As I remember, the main characters played strategy games at playtime, rather than ball games with the rest of the boys, making them outcasts. But one playtime, aliens land in the playground and challenge the children to a battle for the Earth.

There is some kind of playground equipment that becomes the children’s fortress that they defend. The main characters organise the rest of the children to fight off the invasion. The aliens were highly militaristic and I think insect-like.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When did you read this, and roughly when do you think it was published?

Comment: As this is a short story it is definitely not Ender's Game. But there are some interesting similarities to the Battle School game activities and that Ender and his squad are considered "outcasts".  Even the enemy being insectoidal matches.

Comment: @beichst "Ender's game" started as a novelette, which some might interpret as a short story. However, it's quite stripped down from the novel. The parts where Ender was an "outcast", as well as when he took it upon himself to give his friends extra training,  aren't in it.

Comment: @spencer, you raise a good point.  Some folks might recall the novelette as a short story.  But even if that is the case, I think you correctly pointed out that the cut down novelette does not include much of the relevant overlap material so would be less likely to be remembered like what the OP listed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't understand why people comment instead of answering.

FWIW I jump in and suggest [Ender's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game), by Orson Scott Card. It occurred to me just by reading the title of your question.

It matches everything you mention. It is a rather long novel, but I understand it started as a shorter story, which may be what you read.

Comment: "It matches everything you mention." Can you give an example of where "aliens land in the playground" and "There is some kind of playground equipment that becomes the children’s fortress that they defend. " in *Ender's Game*? Because I forgot that part.

Comment: Hmmmmm... Looks like I read too fast. I missed the part about "aliens land" and concentrated only on "challenge the children for a battle fo the Earth" which is what actually happened, though the children did not know the challenge was real and believed it was still the game.

Comment: It's probably not _Ender's Game_.  But I like "Orson Scoot Card".  He should change his name to that.

Comment: @davidbak I am lysdexic... ;)